# javascript variable to php script using ajax

Tags: javascript, php

I have the below button in my **index.php** file.

```
<form action="update.php" method="post" >
<button onclick="myFunction()">Update</button>
</form>
```

I have the below javascript function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'update.php',
        data: {
            source1: "some text",
        },
        success: function( data ) {
            console.log( data );
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

I am using the above javascript function to send the javascript variable to the php server side script file (**update.php**). I am accessing the variable in **update.php** as below.

```
$src1= $_POST['source1'];
echo $src1;
```

However, I am not able to see the variable in the output of **update.php** file. What am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do it on the `submit` event of the form and cancel the default behavior. First set the button type to submit the form:

```
<form action="update.php" method="post" >
  <button type="submit">Update</button>
</form>
```

Then add the event in JavaScript:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing an answer. I have more than 2 buttons. So, I tried to assign an id to this form and in my javascript function, I tried using the ID name. However, it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `.done` method instead of `success` parameter which is supposed to be deprecated.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'update.php',
    data: {
        source1: "some text",
    },

}).done(function( data ) {
        console.log( data );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer. I tried it. But am not getting any luck.

Comment: Have you checked the request your web browser made and the response it received?

Comment: I see 200 OK for my request. However, I am not able to verify the response. I am using google chrome browser and not sure on how to check the console data.

Comment: right click and select inspection mode, tab console is the console output. tab network contains all the requests and responses.

Comment: If you know how to use this, you almost never need to ask a question ever again

Comment: Ok. I am not seeing anything in the tab console.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45857/discussion-between-ram-esh-and-gigadot)